# Best traffic / performance / usage monitoring module?

Tags: performance, monitoring, usage-statistics

Are there any open source (or I guess commercial) packages that you can plug into your site for monitoring purposes? I'd like something that we can hook up to our ASP.NET site and use to provide reporting on things like:

- performance over time
- current load
- page traffic
- SQL performance
- PU time monitoring

Ideally in c# :)

With some sexy graphs.

**Edit**: I'd also be happy with a package that I can feed statistics and views of data to, and it would analyse trends, spot abnormal behaviour (e.g. "no one has logged in for the last hour. is this Ok?", "high traffic levels detected", "low number of API calls detected")  and generally be very useful indeed. Does such a thing exist?

At my last office we had a big screen which showed us loads and loads of performance counters over a couple of time ranges, and we could spot weird stuff happening, but the data was not stored and there was no way to report on it. Its a package for doing this that I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.serverdensity.com/

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that google analytics is not an accurate representation of web site usage. This is because the web beacon (web bug) used on the page does not always load for these reasons:

1. Google analytics servers are called by millions of pages every second and can not always process the requests in a timely fashion.
2. Users often browse away from a page before the full page has loaded and thus there is not enough time to load Googles web beacon to record a hit.
3. Google analytics require javascript to be installed which can be disabled.
4. Quite a few (but not substantial amount) of people block google-analytics.com from their browsers, myself included.

The physical log files are the best 'real' representation of site usage as they record every request. Alternatively there are far better 'professional' packages, of which Omniture is my favourite, which have much better response times, alternative methods for recording actions and more functionality.

Comment: Agreed in general, BUT:

1. Is this actually true or just FUD? Got any references to some evidence?

Also, the advantage of google analytics is that it's front-end, and can determine many things that back-end processing cannot - e.g. browser-specific info. A bespoke solution is the only alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately i have not got any figures to hand but i know that when comparing google stats to real stats there was always a large discrepancy. Im not alone either, see http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-reliable-is-google-analytics for example.

Server logs are the most reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after things like server data, would [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) be something you're after?
It's not really a webserver type stats program though, I have no idea how it would scale.

Edit:

I've also just found [Splunk Swarm](http://wiki.splunk.com/Splunk_swarm), if you're interested in something that looks "cool".

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) is free (up to 50,000 hits per month I think) and is easy to setup with just a little javascript snippet to insert into your header or footer and has great detailed reports, with some very nice graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is quick to set up and provides more sexy graphs than you can shake a stick at.

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

Not Invented here but it's on my todo list to setup.
http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Comment: looks too purely web-oriented. I'd like to feed in stats on hardware performance, business actions etc.

Answer (score 0):

[@Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080/best-traffic-performance-usage-monitoring-module#18098)

Looks like they've raised the limit. Not very surprising, it is google after all ;)

> This free version is limited to 5 million pageviews a month - however, users with an active Google AdWords account are given unlimited pageview tracking.

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55543

Comment: Looks very nice, but we get a million hits a day unfortunately! Also I'd like to be able to feed some server data into it, like cache capacity, CPU times etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use external monitoring tools, which will monitor the web performance from outside the firewall by simulating end user activities.

Catchpoint Systems has an interesting approach that requires very little coding and gives you the performance stats from outside the datacenter and from inside the asp.net (like processing time, etc)

http://www.catchpoint.com/products.html