# What tools do you use to monitor a web service?

Tags: monitoring, production

From basic things likes page views per second to more advanced stuff like cpu or memory usage. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think someone has asked the same type of question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080/best-traffic-performance-usage-monitoring-module#19502)?  Though I'm not too sure how helpful it is.

For CPU usage, etc, I would try [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/), or maybe something like [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Web service or web site?  Since you mention page views: I believe you mean web site.

Google Analytics will probably give you everything you need to track usage statistics and best of all is free under most circumstances.

You might also want to monitor site up-time and have something to send email alerts if the site is down for some reason. We've used Nagios in the past and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using monit (http://www.tildeslash.com/monit/) for years. It monitors CPU and memory usage as well as downtime for apache/mysql/etc... you can also configure it to notify you of outages and automatically restart services in real time.

I also use munin for reporting: http://munin.projects.linpro.no/

If you want reports on pageviews and whatnot, [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is the best I've used.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org) for general machine monitoring on Linux and I pretty much rely on [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) for website reporting - I know that's not for everyone since some folks have privacy concerns about giving all their site data to Google.

Both are free and easy to install (Nagios is generally available through apt-get and Analytics is a pretty easy install on a site).

Nagios, however, can be a bear to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I cast my vote for [monit](http://www.tildeslash.com/monit/) as well.   The nice thing about is that it understands apache-status info and can notify/take actions when say 80% of max num of apache workers are in "busy" state.

but you need something else for hardware and general monitoring, something SNMP-aware, like zennos or zabbix

Answer (score 0):

[Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) and [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) provide very nice interfaces and pre-built scripts for rrdtool. They can also monitor multiple servers and send out warnings and alerts through naigos.